# How to sum number of doubles?

Tags: haskell, double, precision

How can I sum `Double`s? I thought `sum` would work out of the box, and when I just use type inference it does indeed seem to, but when I give a type signature fixing the output type to `Double` the sum goes infinite!

This doesn't work:

```
doubles :: Int -> Int -> Double
doubles maxk maxn =  sum [1/(fromIntegral(i*(j+1)^(2*i)))|i<-[1..maxk],j<-[1..maxn]]
```

I see this behavior:

```
*Main> doubles 20 1500
Infinity
```

However, without a type signature, the same code:

```
doubles maxk maxn =  sum [1/(fromIntegral(i*(j+1)^(2*i)))|i<-[1..maxk],j<-[1..maxn]]
```

Produces a sensible answer:

```
*Main> doubles 20 1500
0.692481179869307
```

What gives?

Comment: Can you please be more clear about what does not work and why? The two codes look identical

Comment: I've tried to make it a bit more clear exactly what you're asking. Please feel free to change any parts of the question back if I've misunderstood what's confusing you.

Answer (score 6):

The second function has a different type that first one.

> (Fractional a1, Integral a2) => a2 -> a2 -> a1

here a2 is any type that has an instance of Integral. Both Int and Integer implement Integral. Integer is an arbitrary precision type: it will hold any number no matter how big, up to the limit of your machine's memory. Int isn't. For example:

> (10::Integer)^100 == 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>
> (10::Int)^100 == 0

The second case can happen in your first function. And then **1/0 == Infinity**

When there is no explicit type declaration Haskell will assume that any natural number literal is, in fact, an Integer. That's why the second function operates on Integers and the result is better